# How to give width and height programatically for collection view cell in ios, swift 3

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I tried to give the height and width for `collectionViewCell` , programatically. I used following method:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let viewWidth = self.deviceWidth/3 - 5
        let viewHeight = viewWidth

        return CGSize(width :100,height: 100)
    }
```

This didn't work. even this method didn't show as a hint. Help me with this. Is there any other delegate method to set the cell width and height programmatically in Swift 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` is [`UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout) protocol's method, so setting `delegate` and `datasource` of `collectionView` is not enough, you need to implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` with your custom class where you have added `collectionView` to call `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol's methods. So implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` like below example:

`class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {`

Answer (score 1):

Pls sure your class must implement **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    ...
}
```

And then write this delegate method in your class:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100) // The size of one cell
}
```

Hope it will help you...

Answer (score 0):

This methods always work. Please first ensure that this method is executed ot not. If not, the write delegate `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
   :
   :
}
```

And dont forget to bind the delegate and datasource of UICollectionView either from storyboard or by code `collectionView.delegate = self` and `collectionView.datasource = self`