# UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate insetForSectionAt never called

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

**swift3**

I need to use some `optional` methods of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, however method below is never called.

**insetForSectionAt**

```
optional public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
```

Since `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` inherited from `UICollectionViewDelegate` - all I need to do is to assign `collection'sView` delegate:

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self.delegate
```

Note that everything else works fine and methods like `sizeForItem` or `cellForItem` gets called.

Comment: Compare with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41182854/how-to-give-width-and-height-programatically-for-collection-view-cell-in-ios-sw

Comment: those answers seems not usefull for me -> "implement custom flow layout class" => nope, you dont have to. Or they suggest support flowDelegateProtocol => but it doesn't matter, it's just for compiler

Comment: You need to implement it now, try once implementing `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` it will sure work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure if you have implemented UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in your class like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

//...your code here
```

}

Comment: Didn't you say that the method wasn't called?

Comment: that strange but got it working, i'll make answer but accept yours as well